# Migrating from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, resources

I am looking at a job which requires C#. I have used it a few times but no where near competent. I do however know Java and OOP so I was wondering if anyone knew some good resources or tutorials for learning C# by Java equivalents or C# without explaining basic OOP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This MSDN article compares Java and C# which might help you move over:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228602.aspx

Another comprehensive article:

http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html

Plus this book seems to have a pretty good rating on amazon.com for java developers:

[http://www.amazon.com/Java-Developers-Pro-Developer-Allen-Jones/dp/0735617791](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735617791)